¿Como puedo insertar datos en 2 tablas al mismo tiempo?
Estoy iniciando en esto y estoy desarrollando un proyecto personal usando PDO
Estoy usando este código y requiero agregar los mismos datos a 2 o mas tablas. si me pudieran apoyar con sus respectivos comentarios.
Gracias!!!
$seccion = $_GET['seccion'];
$casilla = $_GET['casilla'];
$zona = $_GET['zona'];
$user_creacion = $_GET['user_creacion'];

date_default_timezone_set("America/Monterrey" );
$fechaHora = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$estado = '1';

$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_resultados_republica (seccion, casilla, zona, user_creacion, fyh_creacion, estado)
                            VALUES (:seccion, :casilla, :zona, :user_creacion, fyh_creacion, :estado)");
  
$sentencia->bindParam(':seccion', $seccion);
$sentencia->bindParam(':casilla', $casilla);
$sentencia->bindParam(':zona', $zona);
$sentencia->bindParam(':user_creacion', $user_creacion);
$sentencia->bindParam(':fyh_creacion', $fechaHora);
$sentencia->bindParam(':estado', $estado);

  
if($sentencia->execute()){
    //echo "Usuario agregado correctamente.";
    header('Location: '.$URL.'/resultados/crearcasilla.php');
}


Simplemente tienes que preparar otra sentencia distinta, hacerle los bindParam y ejecutarla, es decir, lo mismo que haces con $sentencia, pero con otra variable.

Nada te impide volver a ejecutar la misma consulta con otra tabla, incluso hasta puedes usar otro objeto PDO con un servidor diferente. Ahora bien, si necesitas agregar la misma información 2, 3, etc veces en distintas tablas de la misma base de datos, hay un mal diseño en el modelo del proyecto.

Usa $sentencia2. Aunque como ya te dijeron, lo normal es que no haya información repetida en tablas de la DB. Eso es parte de la normalización de datos.
